# Can the "Design Pattern" be applied to different programs?

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern, publish-subscribe

I have 2 programs A, B. If A finishes, I want B to know that and start to run, using data from result of A.

A is a .NET web application. I think that's not kept alive in memory all the time, right? Only alive if requested from browsers, right?

Before, A and B are the 2 functions of the same program. But B program fails sometimes due to business reasons. And even if B doesn't fail, it's time-consuming and makes the clients wait for too long and be unhappy. So I separated B out. Clients using A smoothly and are happy. B do staff in background.

My current design is: when A finishes, A saves the data into database. B is a windows service. It checks the database every 5 minutes and start to run if finds new jobs. A, B doesn't know each other.

The boss asked why idle for 5 minutes? I answered because that's the simplest way of implement some of our business. I didn't design much.

So I went to read materials, and found that the `Observer Pattern` seemed like what I want. After several readings, I think the `Observer Pattern` can only be applied to classes in the same program, and the classes and objects are in memories.

I'm not sure if my question is: Can the `GOF Design Patterns` be applied to different programs?

or: How does something like RabbitMQ implements this real-time-processing kind of requirements?

I cannot imagine to set check interval of 5 minutes to a really small time period. That's a lot of burden to cpu.

**EDIT: I have come into this explanation about `Observer` and `Publish/Subscribe`, which I think is useful to those seeing this thread from search.**

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript

> Differences Between The Observer And Publish/Subscribe Pattern
>
> The Observer pattern requires that the observer (or object) wishing to receive topic notifications must subscribe this interest to the object firing the event (the subject).
>
> The Publish/Subscribe pattern however uses a topic/event channel which sits between the objects wishing to receive notifications (subscribers) and the object firing the event (the publisher). This event system allows code to define application specific events which can pass custom arguments containing values needed by the subscriber. The idea here is to avoid dependencies between the subscriber and publisher.
>
> This differs from the Observer pattern as it allows any subscriber implementing an appropriate event handler to register for and receive topic notifications broadcast by the publisher.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the Observer Pattern is more for designing OO classes.  One pattern that can work between programs is the publish-subscribe model, and I think that would be a good fit for what you describe.  Process B subscribes to certain events that are triggered by A.  This is typically mediated by a service architecture; eg, process A and B are web applications (or WCF/MVC/Web API), and there's a third application that mediates the publish-subscribe pattern.  So when A completes, it sends an event to the pub-sub service; and the pub-sub service sends out a notification to all subscribers to that event (in your case, application B).

You can implement this pattern yourself; there are also .NET frameworks such as [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com/) that implement it.

Comment: I researched about NServiceBus. It seems like what I want. Thanks. But I've also seen some articles said 'Observer Pattern' == 'Publish-Subscribe Pattern'. What's that mean? And if I don't want to use MSMQ, will NServiceBus have other alternatives?

Comment: I have another server machine runs debian. Do I have something similar in linux/python?

Comment: @hbrlovehaku Yes, on second thought, I suppose observer and pub/sub are the same thing... you'll be using web services / RPCs, but the design pattern is the same.  As far as Linux/Python, sorry, I can't help you there as I just don't know.

Comment: OK there comes the initial question. What I read about 'Observer' implement the logic using 2 classes: Subject, Observer. But the `NServiceBus` suggest a 3rd party to manage the messages between Subject and Observer. How can that still be `Observer Pattern`?

Comment: Well this is an extended Observer Pattern. Called Mediator.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "pull model" is inefficient and wastes resources.
The publish-subscribe model is better option.
In this  [link](http://goo.gl/vDpZU) you can see a note that will guide you.
The examples are in Java but it is easy to implement .net.

Answer (score 0):

A comparable mechanism of the observer pattern between applications is to use *remote method invocation* or *remote procedure call* (so it is called in java). In .Net it should be under: [Windows Communication Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119%28VS.90%29.aspx).

Application A sends an (asyncronous) message to Application B by the WCF. It is also possible that Application B might first register itself as message addressee, but in case that A now and then crashes that will not the best bet.

Comment: I don't think WCF get the point. I've not used WCF but read something related. I think WCF is some contract between processes. I'd rather use json and define the contract with documentation. Please tell me if I misunderstand it.

Comment: I do not know .Net architecture well. I thought via *WCF* it is possible to send/recieve async messages between applications. But however you actually implement it, it works the following way: *subject* (app A) sends a message to (notifies) *observers* (app B). Then the observer triggers any action (eg looking up the database).